# Equality of mixed partials proof

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to prove the equality of mixed partials.  My book has a proof but it's only for functions $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ (and then that can be extended to $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^n$ by applying the result componentwise).  The author claims that the function's domain is restricted to $\Bbb R^2$ "for ease of notation" -- implying that the result should hold for higher spaces as well, but I don't see it so I'm trying to prove it myself.  I start by defining basically the same function they do, but then my proof veers off a bit and I'm running into trouble.  I can see where the author is getting to but I can't seem to get there myself.  I'd appreciate some help.  Anyway, here's my proof:

Define $S(h) = [f(\vec a + h(\hat e_i + \hat e_j)) - f(\vec a + h\hat e_i)]-[f(\vec a+h\hat e_j)-f(\vec a)]$.  Then by definition

$$\begin{align}S(h) &= [h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(\vec a+h\hat e_i) + o(h)] - [h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(\vec a) + o(h)] \\ &= h\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(\vec a+h\hat e_i)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(\vec a)\right] + o(h) \\ &= h\left[h\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(\vec a)+o(h)\right] + o(h) \\ &= h^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(\vec a) + o(h^2) + o(h) \\ &\implies \frac{S(h)}{h^2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(\vec a) + \frac{o(h^2)}{h^2} + \frac{o(h)}{h^2}\end{align}$$

Here's where I have a problem.  My book doesn't use this $o(h)$ approach and so they end up with $\frac{S(h)}{h^2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(\xi,\eta)$ and can take a limit because of the continuity of $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$.  But I can't take a limit because $o(h)$ is only guaranteed to go to $0$ faster than $h$, not $h^2$.  Can anyone see a way of finishing the proof my way?